Dynamically Generating Images from HTML/CSS Templates with Custom Data
I have a collection of banner templates (written in HTML and CSS) stored in a database. Each template contains placeholders for a logo, a heading, and a subheading area. I need to dynamically generate new images based on these templates by replacing the placeholders with custom data (e.g., a specific logo, a custom heading, and a custom subheading).
My goal is to find an efficient and scalable solution that can handle a large number of templates and generate images on-the-fly or in batch mode. Ideally, the solution should be able to:

Load the template HTML/CSS from the database.
Identify the placeholders (e.g., logo area, heading area, subheading area) within the templates.
Replace the placeholders with the provided custom data (logos, text, etc.).
Generate new images with the customized content.

I'm open to using AI tools, libraries, APIs, or any other suitable technologies that can address this requirement. Performance and scalability are important factors to consider, as the solution may need to handle a high volume of requests or generate a large number of images simultaneously.
I would appreciate any recommendations, code examples, or guidance on how to approach this problem effectively. Please share your expertise and any relevant resources or tools that could be helpful in implementing this solution.
